# How to make datepicker appear on every row in table php

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I am having a problem trying to display datepicker on every table row , which are all textfields (9 in total), The datepicker only appears on the first row under the column Date, the other 8 remain as ordinary textfields. I would appreciate some help on how i could sort this problem. Here is my code:

//Datepicker function() code

```
<script>
 $('.datepicker').each(function(){
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

//Print datepicker tablerow code.

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="datepicker" class="datepicker"></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: That should work just fine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need for `$.each`:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are missing is a

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    //do stuff here
});
```

Maybe your code fires before the DOM is completely loaded specially if it's placed in the `<head>` section, and it only catches the first input.
It's just a speculation in absence of more details on this.

Also, you should avoid printing strings of static HTML using the server side script.